# Katex - how to jump to the equation

Tags: javascript, latex, katex

I want to use katex (https://katex.org/docs/support_table) to generate math symbols on my website. The environments like `align` generates numbers like below[image]

I'd like to add a button which scroll to lets say equation 3. What would be the better way to do that? Katex doesnt generate `id` for equation numbers. Should I postprocess the output of `katex` and add it?